# How to go from iptables to pf?

Tags: iptables

Hi how to is possible to convert iptables rules into pf rules file?

Comment: Are you talking about Pfsense?

Answer (score 4):

One method would be to use the application [FWBuilder](http://www.fwbuilder.org/). It is primarily a graphical application that can be used to manage firewall rule sets. It also, however, has an import/export feature that can be used to translate between different firewall types. And yes, both iptables and pf are supported.

---

So it looks like FWBuilder is more tricksome than I remembered. While you can import rulesets from Cisco and IPTables, you cannot directly export. I went through the process of translating a desktop IPTables ruleset from iptables to pf, and it was a fair amount of effort. Whether it is easier than learning pf syntax and doing a manual conversion, I don't know. That being said, this is the process I took to go from iptables -> pf using fwbuilder.

1. File -> Import Policy -> Select iptables rule file
2. Set Platform = iptables, click Next
3. Change *New Firewall* type to pf with appropriate Version and Host OS settings
   [image: NewFirewall-Edit][image: FirewallSettings]
4. Create new Interface object
   [image: AddNewInterface]
5. Change Direction in Policy frame to their correct direction (inbound/output/both)
6. Add newly created interface to rules where appropriate
7. Save  to FWBuilder format -- File -> Save As -> Select filename to save as

From this point I used an iterative process to filter out any parse problems that fwbuilder had, primiarily the direction issues above and things like my rule to drop XMAS packets. I did this by issuing the compile commands directly, instead of using the interface.

1. `fwb_pf -v -f ~/sandbox/firewallwork/desktop_firewall -d ~/sandbox -o ~/sandbox/firewallwork/New\ Firewall.fw 'New Firewall'`
2. If no errors, stop, else
3. Fix problem in interface
4. File -> Save
5. goto 1

This will, eventually, leave you with two files that contain your new pf firewall config, `New Firewall.fw`, and `New Firewall.conf`. To reiterate above, after refreshing my memory on the process I am a lot less excited about it as a truly useful solution. However, by comparing the output beside your original ruleset it may help you get a better understanding of how the pf rulesets are developed so you can start managing them yourself.

Comment: How to import I see, but there is't clear how export?

Comment: Admittedly, I cheaped out with the answer. I'll try to update with better instructions (and maybe screenshots) later when I have more time.

Comment: Import current iptables rules (fwbuilder can import only iptables and cisco ACL rules), change firewall type to PF, press "Compile" button.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your talking about Pfsense. No, this isn't possible, you'll have to enter them by hand.

Comment: pf is the OpenBSD software firewall. pfSense, being FreeBSD, uses pf for the firewall portion of the distro.

Comment: well my reply is most likely wrong then... Please move along, noting to see here...

Comment: I think you're spot on either way -- the OP will need to conceptualize the rules and translate them from iptables syntax to pf syntax.  As far as I know there's no tool that does this.